# -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: java, sql, macos, bash, terminal

I'm trying to run the query below in Terminal on OSX. It keeps returning:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I'm sure I'm overlooking something very dumb. If someone could point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it. The command includes the SQL query for the program to execute:

```shell
java -Xmx16g -cp .:lib/* edu.cuny.util.VectorToInstancesConverter train HandednessJ48 “SELECT * FROM collection1.Session1 WHERE Subj_Id!=402 and Subj_Id not in ( select Subj_id from collection1.Session2) AND Subj_Id IN ( SELECT Subj_Id FROM collection1.userdata WHERE 'DominantHand' = 'l' OR 'DominantHand' = 'r')” 12 J48
```

Comment: bash is trying to read `(`, since is a special character in shell scripting, as an instruction to to itself. It needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is when you use `"` bash tries to evaluate anything within it instead you should use `'`, try this:

```
java -Xmx16g -cp .:lib/* edu.cuny.util.VectorToInstancesConverter train 
HandednessJ48 'SELECT * FROM collection1.Session1 WHERE Subj_Id!=402 
and Subj_Id not in ( select Subj_id from collection1.Session2) AND 
Subj_Id IN ( SELECT Subj_Id FROM collection1.userdata WHERE 
'DominantHand' = 'l' OR 'DominantHand' = 'r')' 12 J48
```

or as @bhesh has specified you can delimit the characters which bash will try to evaluate :

```
java -Xmx16g -cp .:lib/* edu.cuny.util.VectorToInstancesConverter train 
HandednessJ48 "SELECT * FROM collection1.Session1 WHERE Subj_Id!=402 
and Subj_Id not in \( select Subj_id from collection1.Session2\) AND 
Subj_Id IN \( SELECT Subj_Id FROM collection1.userdata WHERE 
'DominantHand' = 'l' OR 'DominantHand' = 'r'\)" 12 J48
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew I was overlooking something trivial.

Comment: The problem is that the posted code uses not regular double quotes, but U+201C and U+201D, which are not recognized as quotes at all. Only parameter expansions and command substitutions are treated differently between single and double quotes, and neither is used here. Using regular ASCII double quotes would work just as well as single quotes.

Comment: Note that using single quotes will actually not work well here, since you cannot embed single quotes inside other quotes. The single quotes that were intended to be passed as part of the SQL query instead close and open the argument being passed to `java`.

Comment: @chepner Yes you are correct about that only parameterexpansions and command substitutions are treated differently between single and double quotes, but I have tested this and it works fine even if you use `'` in select query. It takes the whole as one argument, actually I am also confused why that is happening.

Comment: In this case, there's still one argument because the unquoted parts contain no spaces, so the string still forms one continuous argument. I don't know SQL very well; it's possible the single quotes in this command are optional.